# How to add corresponding elements of of lists of list when some fields are None?

Tags: python

I have a long list of lists which reads similar to

```
List = [['Time', 0, 1, 2, 3, None, None], ['Position',0, 0, 1, 2, None, None], ['Weight',1, 1, 1, 2, None, None],['Time', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['Position',0, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], ['Weight'], [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3]]
```

which when exported to csv looks like

```
Time,      0,  1,  2,  3,    4,    5,
Position,  0,  0,  1,  2, None, None,
Weight,    1,  1,  1,  2, None, None,
Time,      0,  1,  2,  3,    4,    5,
Position,  0,  2,  3,  4,    4,    3,
Weight,    1,  1,  2,  1,    1,    3,
```

Now, I want to append three rows like below at the end.

```
Time,                0,      1,     2,     3,         4,         5,
Total Position,      0,      2,     4,     6,         4,         3,
Total Weight,        2,      2,     3,     3,         1,         3,
```

How can I do this?  The problems I am facing are

1. I can not add None with any other values
2. How can I add elements corresponding to position rows or weight rows only?

Comment: You should really be using `pandas` for this. But what are `x0, x1, x2, x3` etc. suppose to be?

Comment: x's, and y's are floating numbers where a's and b's are integers.

Comment: You should provide sample data that is actually interpretable as code if I were to copy-and-paste it into a terminal. If you are going to go to the trouble of writing out an example, don't use names that won't be defined. Just make up a number!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Though I said the values are floating numbers, I edited these with simple integers. Hope this works for at least test.  And, Sorry for my non professional question. Very new to python and to the community.

Comment: Yes. It should help your question get more attention. Many would turn away if they have to manually enter in values to play around with your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np #use numpy to sum row

def replace_none(line): #change None into 0
    def test(elem):
        return elem if elem is not None else 0
    return np.array([test(elem) for elem in line])

def Total(list_,key):
    line=np.zeros(len(list_[0])-1)
    for l in list_:
        if l[0]==key: # collect the right lines
            line += replace_none(l[1:]) #sum
    return ['Total '+key,*line]

List.append(Total(List,'Position'))
List.append(Total(List,'Weight'))
```